# Sum to closed form?

Tags: calculus, summation, closed-form

I need to evaluate the following summation to closed form:

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (e k n \pi ) \sin (e k (1+n) \pi )}{k \pi  \sin (e k \pi )}$$

where: $n>1$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $e \approx  2.718281828459$

By using the [Abel-Plana formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula), I obtain:
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}f(n) = \int \limits_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx + \frac{1}{2} f(0) + i\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(ix) - f(-ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx
$$

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (e (1+k) n \pi ) \sin (e (1+k) (1+n) \pi )}{(1+k) \pi  \sin (e (1+k) \pi )}=\int_0^{\infty
   } \frac{\sin (e (1+k) n \pi ) \sin (e (1+k) (1+n) \pi )}{(1+k) \pi  \sin (e (1+k) \pi )} \, dk+\frac{1}{2}
   \left(\lim_{k\to 0} \, \frac{\sin (e (1+k) n \pi ) \sin (e (1+k) (1+n) \pi )}{(1+k) \pi  \sin (e (1+k) \pi )}\right)+0$$

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (e (1+k) n \pi ) \sin (e (1+k) (1+n) \pi )}{(1+k) \pi  \sin (e (1+k) \pi )}=\int_0^{\infty
   } \frac{\sin (e (1+k) n \pi ) \sin (e (1+k) (1+n) \pi )}{(1+k) \pi  \sin (e (1+k) \pi )} \, dk+\frac{\csc (e \pi ) \sin
   (e n \pi ) \sin (e (1+n) \pi )}{2 \pi }$$

dosen't seems to work,but I put $n=2$ and calculate numerical the results do not match.

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (2 e (1+k) \pi ) \sin (3 e (1+k) \pi )}{(1+k) \pi  \sin (e (1+k) \pi )} \approx -0.154747$$

by Abel-Plana formula I got: $\approx -0.107417$

Comment: i got a result with Mathematica, should i post it?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner.Yes ,we will see what it is.

Comment: see here $$\frac{1}{8} i \pi  \left(\log \left(1-e^{-i e (2 \pi  n+\pi +1)}\right)-\log \left(1-e^{i e
   (2 \pi  n+\pi +1)}\right)-\log \left(1-e^{-i (e \pi  (2 n-1)+e)}\right)+\log \left(1-e^{i
   (e \pi  (2 n-1)+e)}\right)+\log \left(1-e^{i e (1+\pi )}\right)-\log \left(1-e^{-i e
   (1+\pi )}\right)+\log \left(1-e^{i e (\pi -1)}\right)-\log \left(1-e^{-i e (\pi
   -1)}\right)\right)$$

Comment: The Abel-Plana formula provides an identity under certain assumptions on $f$. Did you check they (do not) hold?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: how would you prove that the given series is convergent? To me it looks highly non trivial to prove that $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\cot(\pi k e)}{\pi k}$ is convergent, for instance. If that can be done, it can be done by exploiting the fact that the irrationality measure of $e$ is well-known (it is $2$) since the whole continued fraction of $e$ is well-known. But if $e$ is replaced by another trascendental number that might fail to hold, and certainly the Abel-Plana formula or the combination of logarithms you show cannot capture such subtlety.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner for $ n=2$ I got: $\approx  -2.4674$.Dosen't yours formula seem to work :(

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: please read carefully my previous comment: it gives that neither the Abel-Plana formula or Dr.'s formula can provide a closed form expression. It is not trivial to prove that the given series $S(e)$ is convergent, and $S(\alpha)$, when defined, is expected to be a highly discontinuous function.

Comment: And you cannot apply (complex) analytic techniques to a function that is heavily discontinuous.